# Simple time and half calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple time and half calculator in HTML and JavaScript, but for some reason, when I click the <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button, the P element does not show the result.

Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/chrissylvester10/pen/wJxder

```
html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Time and Half Calculator</h1>
        <input id="fare" size="7" maxlength="7" name="fare" style="width:75px" value="0" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculator()">
        <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
</html>

var fare = document.getElementById("#fare").value;

function calculator() {
    var result = fare / 2 + fare;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Please fork it because I need to see the changes.

Comment: Does it actually start with "`html>`"?

Comment: Sorry I missed that while copying it.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you don't need the `#` in `var fare = document.getElementById("#fare").value;`.

It should be `var fare = document.getElementById("fare").value;`

That line of code should also be inside the function, so it will read the new value every time you change it, otherwise, it will just return 0.

Lastly, you want to parse the number so it isn't misread as a string.

```
function calculator() {
  var fare = parseInt(document.getElementById("fare").value);
  var result = fare / 2 + fare;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

edit:

A much simpler way to do this would be

```
function calculator() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fare").value*1.5;
}
```

Comment: Also have in mind that "value" might be a string so when you do: fare / 2 + fare it will concatenate the string, and not add the actual value... try:
  var result = fare / 2 + parseInt(fare);

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value at the start and not the actual value.

Solution: Move the `fare` declaration inside of the function.

Small change: Get only `fare` as id.

```js
function calculator() {
  var fare = +document.getElementById("fare").value,
      result = fare / 2 + fare;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<h1>Time and Half Calculator</h1>
<input id="fare" size="7" maxlength="7" name="fare" style="width:75px" value="0" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculator()">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about to enclose your Javascript into `<script>` tags? 
And remove `#` from `fare`.